# asp.net master page does not recognize new controls in code behind on build

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

I'm working on relatively outdated asp.net website (not web app) project.

I was asked to do some changes in the master page, which I did and it works fine when I run locally.

The error is happening when I want to build and publish the website, I'm getting error message that the name 'XXX' does not exist in the current context, although I'm able to access the control by their id in the code behind file.

This is what I have:

```
<div class="mainLogin">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="loginEntry" CssClass="login-name" placeholder="Username or email address" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="passwordEntry2" CssClass="login-password" placeholder="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                            <div class="login-remember-me">
                                <input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="chkRememberme2" />
                                <label>Remember me</label>
                            </div>
                            <button class="login-submit orange-button" runat="server" OnServerClick="btnLogin_OnServerClick" ID="btnLogin">Login <div class="arrow-right"></div></button>
                        </div>
```

It all works fine when I run that locally but when I try to build and publish this is the error I'm getting:

[image]

The event which is happening in the code file:

```
protected void btnLogin_OnServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (loginEntry.Text != string.Empty && passwordEntry2.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            logInProc(loginEntry.Text, passwordEntry2.Text, chkRememberme2.Checked);
        }
    }
```

And the master page directive:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>
```

Code file:

```
public partial class MasterPage : ParentMasterPage
{
//master page code here
}
```

If I remove those new controls and new functionality, I'm able to run the project without any issue.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: have you tried to clean your solution and build it again ? still not worked then restart the IDE

Comment: tried restarting the IDE, restarting the PC. There is no clean option for the solution. I'm using VS2013

Comment: Check if this controls are inside some other... (child of an other)

Answer (score 1):

Try To Clean the solution then rebuilt it

if not work then go to **deisgner.cs** page then check that the entry for above text boxes are there or not? fix it there

Comment: there is no designer file and there is no clean option

Comment: @Laziale: it should be there check again

Comment: asp web form contain .cs file and designer file, expend the web form arrow

Or Kindly show me the screenshot

Comment: @AhsanAzizAbbasi its website project its not a web app project, please keep that in mind, I'm not sure if it makes difference, but I think it does.

Comment: designer is not available in vs 2012 and newer version, website and app has nothing to do here with designer page.

try to retype the code, this also happens when you copy the code.

Comment: so yes, I'm using vs2013. I tried recreating the files both the markup and the cs file, nothing works.

Comment: let me search more and get back to you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99923/discussion-between-laziale-and-ahsan-aziz-abbasi).